# Find all $(a,b)\in\Bbb{N},$ such that $5^a +2^b +8$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all $(a,b)\in\Bbb{N},$ such that $5^a +2^b +8$ is a perfect square.

My approach:
Let $5^a +2^b +8=k^2\implies \bigg(k+5^{\frac{a}{2}}\bigg)\bigg(k-5^{\frac{a}{2}}\bigg)=8\bigg(1+2^{b-3}\bigg).$
The RHS is greater than zero and even,so each of $\bigg(k+5^{\frac{a}{2}}\bigg)$ and $\bigg(k-5^{\frac{a}{2}}\bigg)$ is even and $k$ is odd.
$1+2^{b-3}$ is even only when $b=3.$
Case(1): When $b=3,k^2 =5^a +16;$ Let $k=2m+1\implies 4m^2 +4m+1=5^a +16$ or $4m(m+1)=5^a +15=5\bigg(5^{a-1}+3\bigg).$
If $m$ is odd,$m+1$ is even and vice-versa.
Equating odd and even parts ,
Sub-case(a): $m+1=5\implies m=4,$ and $4m=16=5^{a-1}+3\implies 5^{a-1}=13\implies$ no natural number exist.
Sub-case (b): $m=5$ and $4(m+1)=24=5^{a-1}+3\implies 5^{a-1}=21\implies$ again no natural number exist.
So,there is no natural number solution set exist for $b=3.$
This implies that $1+2^{b-3}$ is odd.
This means that even components:
$k+5^{\frac{a}{2}}=c\bigg(1+2^{b-3}\bigg).$
And $8=8\bigg(k-5^{\frac{a}{2}}\bigg)......(A).$ where $c$ is even .
From equation $(A),$ $c$ has to be non-zero even factor of $8,$ but not $8$ because otherwise $k-5^{\frac{a}{2}}=1$ and odd.
So, $c=(2,4).$
Case(2): When $c=2$
$k-5^{\frac{a}{2}}=4$
$k+5^{\frac{a}{2}}=2\bigg(1+2^{b-3})\implies 5^{\frac{a}{2}}=2^{b-3}-1$
Or $2^{b-3}-5^{\frac{a}{2}}=1.$
The only $a$ and $b$ for which this works is $a=2$ and $b=4\implies k=7.$
There are other solutions too!

And I have no clue how to proceed from here,also if any other way is possible,then please try to show here.
Thank you for each and everyone trying to indulge in solving it!

Is there any complete solution?

Comment: It is very unclear what you mean by "This means that even components: ..." Why should $k+5^{\frac{a}{2}}$ contain the entire factor $1+2^{b-3}$?

Also, you can spare yourself some work by looking at congruence conditions. Looking at mod $4$, you immediately get that $b$ is even, since $k^2=1$ mod $4$ ($1$ is the the only odd quadratic residue). Now, using mod $3$ in a similar way, you get that $a$ must be even. Slightly more subtle, using mod $5$ you get that $4$ divides $b$. 

A brute force search suggests the only solutions are $(2,4)$ and $(2,8)$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim I mean to say that $c$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Equation: $2^b + 5^a + 8 = N^2$
where $a$, $b$ and $N$ are some natural numbers.

**1. Case $a = 0$:**
For $a = 0$, the equation becomes $2^b + 9 = N^2$.
$2^b = (N+3)(N-3)$.
Let $2^{k2} = N+3$ and $2^{k1} = N-3$, where $k_2 > k_1$ and $k_1 + k_2 = b$.
$2^{k2} - 2^{k1} = 6$.
This implies $2^{k1}(2^{k2-k1}-1) = 2 \times 3$.
Forced by this, $k_1 = 1$ and thus $N = 5$.
Consequently, $2^b = 16$ and $b = 4$, with $k_2 = 3$.
Therefore, $(a, b) = (0, 4)$.

**2. Case $a = 1$:**
For $a = 1$, the equation becomes $2^b + 13 = N^2$.
Note that $N$ must be odd, and $N^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.
Therefore, $2^b + 13 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, leading to $2^b \equiv 4 \pmod 8$.
Thus, $b = 2$ and $17 = N^2$ which leads to a contradiction.
Hence, there are no integer solutions for $a = 1$.

**3. Case $a = 2$:**
For $a = 2$, the equation becomes $2^b + 33 = N^2$.
It is clear that $N$ must be odd, and hence $2^b \equiv 0 \pmod 8$, implying $b \geq 3$.
Considering $2^b \equiv N^2 \pmod 3$, with $N^2 \equiv 1 \text{ or } 0 \pmod 3$ depending on whether $N$ is divisible by 3, and $2^b \equiv 2 \text{ or } 1 \pmod 3$ depending on whether $b$ is odd or even, we conclude that $b$ must be even. Let $b = 2p$, and the equation becomes $33 = (N+2^p)(N-2^p)$.
Applying unique prime factorization, we consider the following cases:

- Case 1: $N+2^p = 11$ and $N-2^p = 3$, implying $N = 7$ and $p = 2$.
- Case 2: $N+2^p = 33$ and $N-2^p = 1$, implying $N = 17$ and $p = 4$.
  Combining the results, we have $(a, b) = (2, 4)$ or $(2, 8)$.

**4. Case $a > 2$:**
For $a > 2$, the equation becomes $2^b + 5^a + 8 = N^2$.
Since $N$ must be odd, we have $2^b + 5^a \equiv N^2\equiv 1 \pmod 8$.
Notice that $5^a \equiv 5 \text{ or } 1 \pmod 8$ depending on whether $a$ is odd or even, and $2^b \equiv 2, 4, \text{ or } 0 \pmod 8$ depending on whether $b = 1, 2, \text{ or } >2$.

- **Case 4.1: $a$ is odd and $b = 2.$**
  The equation becomes $5^a + 12 = N^2$.
  As $N^2 \equiv 1 \text{ or } 0 \pmod 3$, depending on whether $N$ is divisible by $3$ or not. This contradict with $5^a \equiv 2\pmod 3$ if $a$ is odd.
- **Case 4.2: $a$ is even and $b > 2.$**
  By considering modulo $3$, $2^b \equiv 1 \equiv N^2 \pmod 3$ which implies that $b$ is odd and $N \equiv 1 \pmod 6$.

(Here is the incomplete result that can currently be deduced. There were several errors in the previous deductions. Thank you for pointing them out.)

In summary:

- For $a = 0$: $(a, b) = (0, 4)$
- For $a = 2$: $(a, b) = (2, 4)$ or $(2, 8)$
- No integer solutions exist for $a = 1$
- For $a > 2$, the most important part, after multiple attempts, i still encounter difficulties in completing the proof.

Comment: use "$" to start a tex command and end it with another one

Comment: What about in case 4, when a is odd and b=2, and when a is even and b>2?

Comment: $a$ is odd and $b=2$, $5^a+2^2=1+4=5\pmod 8$ contradicts with $N^2 = 1 \pmod 8$. Similarly,  when $a$ is even and $b>2$, $5^a+2^2=5+0\pmod 8$ which also leads to the contradiction.